# Disable accessibility in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard, drag

I have buttons below a UIView that covers the whole screen and every time I try to modify its position I have to drag that view out of the screen in order for it to temporarily stop covering the buttons. I was wondering if there was a way to disable the view's accessibility in storyboard so I don't accidentally keep touching it or possibly another solution?

Comment: I think its not possible but another workaround could be you create a new storyboard & keep a copy of your viewcontroller on it so that even if you accidentally messed up with your current view controller you have its copy in another storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck "Installed" in the Attributes Inspector. Doing so will treat this view as if it does not exist in the current size class. Therefore clicking and dragging will not grab onto this view even if it is positioned on top of other elements. Just be sure to recheck Installed when you wish to run the app, otherwise it will not appear.